# Postgres math expression calculcated for each row in table

Tags: sql, math, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, supposing a table like the following:

```
 12184 |               4 |          83
 12183 |               3 |         171
 12176 |               6 |          95
```

How can I compute a math expression for each row in the table?

For example, to divide column 2 by column 3, such that the output would be:

```
 12184 |   0.04819277108
 12183 |   0.01754385965
 12176 |   0.06315789474
```

My instinct was to try:

```
SELECT col1, col2 / col3 FROM table_name;
```

But that return the ceiling (ie. rounded-down) integer part, I need the floating point value.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Typical cast trick needed because col2 and col3 are integers (so result is by default an integer)

```
select col1, col2/col3*1.0 from table
```

or

```
select col1, col2/col3::float from table
```

or (SQL Standard way)

```
select col1, col2/cast(col3 as float) from table
```

Comment: Thanks very much all. 

I actually used the following:

SELECT col1, cast(col2 as float) / cast(col3 as float) FROM table;

Is there any reason to preffer one way opposed to another?

Comment: See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/typeconv.html for details. In fact I prefer your way, as it's standard, the ::type form is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: And, as you can see from my examples, you can get away casting only the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic expressions in SELECT clause, like this:

```
SELECT col1 / col2 AS new_name
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2/col3 from table;
```

Should work.  Aren't col2 and col3 numeric?

Comment: Yes, however I require the floating point value, and Postgres is only returning the integer part.

Answer (score 0):

Try query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 / col3::float FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PgSql the columns are typed. So if you want to operator on them; you need to cast the column.

suppose you have a column 'minutes' and you wanna add '+5' in every values of column 'mintues'

Because you are adding and integer value the minutes column must be a integer only then the addition can be performed.

hence incorrect way:

`select *, minutes+5 from my table` >> syntax error

`select *, minutes::int + 5 from  mytable` >> give the output